# Is possible to take only partial data backup from sql server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, windows

i'm working on windows application in c#,there is one requirement like i need to take database backup from one location & restore that to some other location database on specific condition like from date - to date.
**Is possible to take only partial data backup from sql server 2008 r2? otherwise please let know other way to do achieve same result?**

 Note : partial data backup in the sense may be this weeks data i.e. 08/25/2014 to 08/30/2014 whatever data was updated in sql table excluding data before or after this date.

Comment: What is your definition of a _partial data backup_

Comment: partial data backup in the sense may be this weeks data i.e. 08/25/2014 to 08/30/2014 whatever data was updated in sql table excluding data before or after this date.

Comment: I don't think that there is a built-in option for that. [Look at this article](http://sqlmag.com/blog/does-sql-server-have-incremental-data-backups) for some starting hints on backup types used by Sql Server

Comment: If you are taking log backups that is the only way to get the exact point in time. You could play differential and full backups to get closer to where you need to be then you can play back the log backups to get up to a certain point in time. Like 09:23 on  thursday point in time.